# Text box display based on drop down list

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list that shows all of the job numbers that are current.  I need a text box to display the "name" equivalent of this number.  The drop down list is based on a query to a separate table within the same database.  The drop down list is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlRef" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataRef" DataTextField="Ref" 
     DataValueField="Ref" style="z-index: 1; left: 155px; top: 68px; position: absolute; 
     width: 115px; height: 29px; bottom: 254px;" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

What I need to do is have the text box tbADName to be associated with a datasource that uses a query such as this select Name from ActiveJobs where Ref = dlRef.DataValueField.

Is this possible or do I need to use another construct to display this information?

Comment: take a look at this [jQuery dropdown list](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use javascript to do this. Add an `onchange=functionName()` in your `asp:DropDownList` and handle the onchange in javascript to change the textbox text to the value in the dropdown list.

EDIT:

you could call the onchange event like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlRef" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataRef" DataTextField="Ref" 
     DataValueField="Ref" style="z-index: 1; left: 155px; top: 68px; position: absolute; 
     width: 115px; height: 29px; bottom: 254px;" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="changeTextBox(this)">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And your script like this:

```
<script>
    function changeTextBox(data) {
        document.getElementById("yourTextBoxId").value = data.value;
    }
</script>
```

If you want the text displayed I'm guessing you should use the text property.

Note: As of html5 the script tags can be used like so without the type attribute.

Comment: I understand the concept.  I would love to know if there is some sample code somewhere that could get me started in the right direction?

Comment: Added more info in my answer

Comment: Sorry, for the delay in getting back.  I found that I can bind the formview control to the dropdown list.  It is very important that you check the postback check box on the drop down list otherwise you don't get the formview refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
onchange="showText(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);"
```

Adding in your dropdown it will be

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlRef" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataRef" DataTextField="Ref" 
     DataValueField="Ref" style="z-index: 1; left: 155px; top: 68px; position: absolute; 
     width: 115px; height: 29px; bottom: 254px;" AutoPostBack="True"
      onchange="showText(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Create a function in java-script

```
function showText(value)
{
   document.getElementById("textboxid").value=value
}
```

### Edit 1

```
<head>
    <title>DropDown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chkind(){
    var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dlRef');
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var a = dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].text;
    textbox.value = a;

    }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlRef" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataRef" DataTextField="Ref" 
 DataValueField="Ref" style="z-index: 1; left: 155px; top: 68px; position: absolute; 
 width: 115px; height: 29px; bottom: 254px;" AutoPostBack="True"
 onchange="chkind()">
    <option>Hi</option>
    <option>Bye</option>
</select><br />
<asp:textbox id="textbox" type="text" runat="server" />
</body>
```

Comment: Two things.  I understand where to put the onchange=functionName(). What I don't understand is where to put the actual function.  Shekhar's code doesn't make sense to me in that it doesn't show how to get the relationship between the number and name into the text box.

Comment: Shekhar, if I understand this would put either HI or BYE into the text box.  I need it to get the name from a datasource that uses the "Ref" number from the dlRef dropdown list.

Comment: Maybe this can be easier.  I have a datasource that selects the "Name" from a table based on the dlRef selection.  My problem now is to attach this result to the text box or label or whatever is easiest.

Comment: do you want to put something in the textbox or lable which is in the dropdown or not?